# Apache pre authentication page using api

Tags: rest, apache, authentication, web-applications

I have kind a puzzle-headed task and I don't know where should I start.
We have a web app that is in our local net. We want to give access to this
app from the outside using Apache.

Basically we want pre-login page on apache that will send user credential using api to our app and receive answer with OTP, which user can write in pre-login page inputbox, send again and in case off success Apache will redirect user to standard apps login page.

Can Apache do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of: you can put an authenticating proxy in front of your app that will propagate the established user identity to the backend. See e.g.: https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc